# Unexpected behavior with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

Unexpected behavior

I have some model:

```
//test.js
var mongoose = require('../utils/mongoose');
var schema1 = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String
})

var schema2 = new mongoose.Schema({
objectsArray: [schema1]
});

schema1.pre('validate', function(next) {
console.log('pre validate schema1');
next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Schema2', schema2);
```

Do save:

```
var o = new require('test')({ objectsArray: [{ name: 'Alex' }] });
o.save(function(err){
console.log('saved');
});
```

After, in console i get:

```
pre validate schema1
pre validate schema1
saved
```

The question is, Why? 
 `schema1.pre('validate')`- appears 2 times, but i expect 1 time?

Comment: Validation is called twice on sub-documents. What for, I don't know, but at least that explains why the hook is triggered twice as well.

Answer (score 2):

I find, answer on my question (thx to Aaron Heckmann)

add the pre hook to the child schema before passing it to the parent.

```
schema1.pre(..)
schema2 = Schema({ array: schema1 })
```